# Finite group $G$ with $\exp(G)=2^{n-1}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be a finite **non abelian** group of order $2^n$ and exponent $2^{n-1}$. What can we say about $G$ ? Does $G$ isomorphic either to the Dihedral group $D_{2^n}$ or to the generalized Quaternion group $Q_{2^n}$ ?

Comment: Or to the semi-dihedral group ${SD}_{2^n}$. The group must have maximal class.

Comment: Thanks @the_fox. What is the semi-dihedral group? and what do you mean by "having maxima class" ? Sorry for the questions, but my knowledge is not wide enough.

Comment: @the_fox there is another family of examples, the groups $\langle x,y \mid x^{2^{n-1}}=y^2=1, yxy = x^{2^{n-2}+1} \rangle$, which do not have maximal class for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Thanks Derek. What do you mean by "maximal class" ?

Comment: A group of order $p^n$ for $p$ prime has nilpotency class at most $n-1$, and examples with class $n-1$ have maximal class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four families of examples, which are most easily defined by presentations:

1. Dihedral groups $\langle x,y \mid x^{2^{n-1}} = y^2 = 1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1} \rangle$ for $n \ge 3$;
2. (Generalized) quaternion groups: $\langle x,y \mid x^{2^{n-1}} =  1, y^2 = x^{2^{n-2}}, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1} \rangle$ for $n \ge 3$;
3. Semidihedral groups: $\langle x,y \mid x^{2^{n-1}}= y^2 = 1, y^{-1}xy=x^{2^{n-2}-1} \rangle$ for $n \ge 4$;
4. Sometimes called modular groups: $\langle x,y \mid x^{2^{n-1}}= y^2 = 1, y^{-1}xy=x^{2^{n-2}+1} \rangle$ for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: If you need a reference for this, it can be found in Theorem 5.4.4 of Gorenstein's book.